# Ajax not triggering success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to send an authentication response in json through the ajax.
In chrome devtools, I get the response of the file **register.ajax.php** 
 on the "NETWORK" but never it is never accepted in javascript file.

In the user.class.php, I check if either the userid/username or the email already exist, if they do, it will send the status as "error" or else "success";

**user.class.php**

```
   public function register_client($uid, $email, $pwd)
  {
  $this->db = DB::getInstance();
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE uid = :uid OR email = :email");
  $stmt->bindParam(":uid", $uid);
  $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $query = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $resultado_uid = $query['uid'];
  $resultado_email = $query['email'];
  if ($resultado_uid || $resultado_email)
     {
        $response_array['status'] = 'error';
        echo json_encode($response_array);



     }
    else
     {
        $response_array['status'] = 'success';
        echo json_encode($response_array);




     $basic_password = $pwd;
     $hashed_password = password_hash($basic_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
     $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_accounts(uid, email, pwd) VALUES (:uid, :email, :pwd)");
     $stmt->bindParam(":uid", $uid);
     $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
     $stmt->bindParam(":pwd", $hashed_password);
     $stmt->execute();


     }
  }
```

Through the ajax file I simply activate the register_client public function whenever the action 'register_client' is set (seems also fine);

**register.ajax.php**

```
<?php
require_once "../header.php";
  if(isset($_POST['action'])) $action = $_POST['action'];

    if($action == 'register_client'){

    $cliente->register_client($_POST['uid'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['pwd']);

    }
```

Register form should be fine(It is just a simple form, the action matches too)

**register.php**

```
      <?php
require_once "header.php";
require_once "nav.php"
?>


<form action="" method="POST">


<input type="text" name="uid" id="uid" placeholder="username"><br>

<input type="email" name ="email" id="email" placeholder="email"><br>

<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="password"><br>

<button name="register_client" id="register_client" type="submit">Register</button>

</form>


<?php 

    include "footer.php";

?>
```

Here is where the problem seems to be emanating, The success function is not retrieving any data. Tried to do console.log(data) in it to see what it gives me, and so far nothing.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#register_client").on("click", function() {
            var uid = $("#uid").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var pwd = $("#pwd").val();




            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'ajax/register.ajax.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'uid': uid,
                    'email': email,
                    'pwd': pwd,
                    'action': 'register_client',
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("it failed");
                }

            });
            return false;
        });


    });
```

Comment: Have you looked on the NET tab of your browser's console to see the raw response? You might find some clues there, like some PHP errors corrupting your response. If that's the case, then fix the errors. Also, you might consider using output buffering to capture the errors, and that would allow you to control how the errors are handled.

Comment: i get the whole <head></head> followed by the success response on the "NETWORK-> response" devtools

Comment: A json response can only be json. You're got to remove all other output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `register.ajax.php` you are not echoing anything. If you want to get an output, then you have to echo `json` or a `string` in `register.ajax.php`

In `register.ajax.php`, if you add `echo "success";` then you will get it in success console log.

If you want to return an `array` then you can use `echo json_encode($yourArrayData);`

Comment: tried that too before, not working, either as string or json

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Titulo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/sweetalert.css">
</head>success

Comment: that is what i get on the network response on chrome devtools, i get the success and the whole header

Comment: remove dattype:json and check

Comment: Now it worked!! without dataType json and i just put a simple echo on the register.ajax.php like you said, Thanks bro!!